# How to redirect a website link of an application to Local Disk

Tags: windows-7, redirection, xampp

I have a legacy software. It downloads Visual C++ Redistributable from this link [vcredist_x86.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/d/d/9/dd9a82d0-52ef-40db-8dab-795376989c03/vcredist_x86.exe) whenever I have to install (In new system or due to OS corrupt whatever). The link is broken now. So the legacy software stops the installation saying it could not download the application.

So I want to use the hosts file to redirect like below

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1           localhost
    127.0.0.1       download.microsoft.com

#   Using port number also does not work.
#   127.0.0.1:8080    download.microsoft.com
```

But this trick didn't work as I navigate "download.microsoft.com" it doesn't redirect to 127.0.0.1.

I used XAMPP server.

Comment: Look at the strings in the software, e.g., using pestudio, https://www.winitor.com/, and try to find the full URL... you might need to emulate that locally. Barring that, it *might* be possible to edit (backward engineer) the software itself to look locally for the file.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I will try.